# AngularUI sortable does not work for more then one applications

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have created angularjs application with sortable list. 
My application can be included to the page few times with other different applications. (Each of this angular applications is isolated user control)

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
});

angular.bootstrap($("#app1"), ['myapp']);
angular.bootstrap($("#app2"), ['myapp']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X2h8W/

For this case ui-sortable works only for last application in a page.
This code: `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);` fixes problem, but I want have few isolated application on a page.

Is this angular-ui bug? Is this some configuration for angular ui?

Comment: Open a bug ticket on the issue. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I have created. Looks like it is angular-ui problem. While it is not resolved I'm using own directive http://jsfiddle.net/AMZSK/