# Multiple angularjs applications for one page

Tags: angularjs

I want to have angular js application for each user control on a page. 
Is it a good practice?

And if it is not allowed, so what is a right way to isolate angularjs modules?

I'm asking because of my question about problem with angular ui:
[AngularUI sortable does not work for more then one applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486976/angularui-sortable-does-not-work-for-more-then-one-applications)

Comment: I know, that it is possible to have multiple apps on a page. My question is: "Is it a good practice?"

Comment: Normally one application is all that is required.  You might find Misko's talk about app organization useful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E87rXWE62WU&t=1m46s